# Getting nil value on textview and button

Tags: swift, random, delegates, textview

Hello im am making an app where the user can press a button and a random link shows upp. I have in the textfile tried to name blblbl.delegate = self but when running the code it suddenly says that all of my textview and buttons has the value of nil.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate,  

NSObjectProtocol {


@IBOutlet weak var firstbutton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var firsttextview: UITextView!


let links = ["http://www.google.com","http://www.yahoo.com",
"http://www.discovery.com"]

var currentLinkIndex : Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    Firsttextview.delegate = self
    configureTextView()
    super.viewDidLoad() 
}

func configureTextView() {

    func textView(firsttextview: UITextView!, shouldInteractWithURL   
URL:
NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {

        let url = NSURL(string:links[currentLinkIndex])
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
        return false
    }  
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func firstaction(sender: UIButton) {

    let random : Int = Int(arc4random()) % 3

    Firsttextview.text = links[random]
    currentLinkIndex = random 
}
```

}

How do a solve this problem? Does i some how have to give the textview and button a value! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to change : 
`Firsttextview.delegate` to `firsttextview.delegate` and 
`Firsttextview.text = links[random]` to `firsttextview.text = links[random]`

I tried to recreate your example by :

- Creating a button in the storyboard
- Creating the textview in the storyboard
- Create + drag and drop to my ViewController Class the IBOutlet firstbutton from the button in the storyboard
- Create + drag and drop to my ViewController Class the IBOutlet firsttextview from the textview in the storyboard
- Create + drag and drop to my ViewController Class the IBAction firstaction from the button in the storyboard

If the button and the label are created in the storyboard, they don't need to be initialized in your code.

By doing this, your code worked for me.

Comment: Thanks i just deleted the Outlets and recreated them and it worked! Thanks! @Etienne